# create network diagram/gantt chart that interacts with MySQL through php

Tags: mysql, html, networking, diagram, gantt-chart

I need to generate network diagram and/or gantt chart from data in a MySQL DB.

Is there any javascript/HTML5 library out there that can do it.

The way I imagine it is each shape on the diagram represents a line item from the DB with the associated info. And the links will be based on the relationship of the items in my DB

It has to be bidirectional (can push data back) and interactive (drag and drop, etc)

I have done a search on stackoverflow, and found some js libraries, just want to get more inputs

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen any of these?

- [PHP Gantt Chart](http://www.grahamsprague.com/graphs/gantt_chart/gantt_non_absolute.php)

[image]

- [PHP Classes Gantt Chart](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/2737-PHP-Generate-project-progress-Gantt-charts.html)

[image]

Comment: No..haven't seen them..But I need something truly interactive, not static images